# Singularity of a modelmatrix that consists of one predictor raised to multiple powers

Tags: regression, matrix, polynomial, matrix-inverse, singular-matrix

I was playing around a little bit with linear regression models in R and wanted to try out whether I can get a perfect fit for a linear model where I have a response $$Y = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
y_1\\
\vdots\\
y_n
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and one predictor $$X = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
\vdots\\
x_n
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I thought I can get a perfect fit for the linear model if I introduce $n-1$ powers of $X$ because then I have as many model parameters as observations. My equations for the model are then $$y_i = a_1x_i + \dots + a_nx_i^n $$ and I thought this can be solved for the parameters. However, I always got the error that the system is singular for the machine. I played a little bit around with the predictor values but this ALWAYS happened as soon as $n$ was sufficiently large, say $n$ = 10 or so. I was wondering why this is the case. I guess this implies that there must be a $j$ such that $X^j$ is approximately a linear combination of $\{X^i|i\neq j\}$, which is not obvious to me.

Comment: There would be no problem if you had infinite precision to use in your calculations.  But since even double precision floats will overflow when you raise a range of numbers exceeding about 32 to the tenth power, it should be no surprise that you run into problems.  Usually it's a bad idea to use such a high power in any model; but if you really must, research *orthogonal polynomials.*

Comment: Could you give an intuition about why the resulting matrix is approximately singular for the machine? There is no problem when I raise different vectors to such high powers, but only if I use the same vector. So it is not because of the high powers per se.

Comment: The problem is that the power functions $x \mapsto x^k$ are intuitively "much alike", resulting in a very ill-conditionned matrix when solving the least squares problem. Taking $x_i$ to be regularly spaced in between $0$ and $1$ (and including a constant in the regression), the matrix of the linear system is nearly $\propto$ the [Hilbert matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix) famous for its very poor condition number.